# How to use multiple ANY operators within one predicate?

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

There are two entities C and P with a many-to-many relationship. I am trying to fetch the C entity, where C contains at least one P which consequently contains at least one C with a specific value for its attribute a.

I am trying something like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY p.c.a = %d ", someValue];
```

However this obviously does not work since P has also a to-many relationship to C. I would need something like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY p.ANY(c).a = %d ", someValue];
```

How would you write such predicate in the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get *all* `C` entities that have a relation to at least one `P` entity, then you can do that with

```
NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"C"];
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"count(p) != 0"];
request.predicate = predicate;
```

assuming that `p` is the one-to-many relationship from `C` to `P`.